# Crontab not running script into php

Tags: linux, cron

I am trying to run some crontab tasks and not all of them are being executed. This is the exact contents of my `crontab -e`

```
@hourly /root/scripts/update.sh
@hourly /root/scripts/twitter/update.sh
```

The first task works, the second does not. Both have `chmod 777`.

The only difference between the two is the latter .sh has this in it:

```
 #! /bin/bash
 php -f updateTwitter.php
```

**So I am wondering if there is an issue with crontab calling a script, that then calls a .php file?**

If I run the script manually (`./update.sh`), it works. I have checked the crontab log and I can see the process being executed.

I am running CentOS6.

Comment: It seems as if the shebang "!/bin/sh" is missing at the beginning on the file. Why not execute the php command directly in crontab (you might need an absolute path to php)?

Comment: I updated the question with the shebang that I am using, forgot to add it. I have tried telling crontab to directly use php and run the php file, though the same thing happens - crontab logs the process without it being executed.

Answer (score 0):

**crontab**

```
MAILTO:you@example.com
@hourly cd /root/scripts/twitter; update.sh
```

**In update.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/php updateTwitter.php
```

Assuming updateTwitter.php is in /root/scripts/twitter

Comment: I updated my crontab to be like yours, I also updated the .sh to be like yours. The same is happening though. I added `echo "starting" > log.txt` to the .sh file to see if crontab is even starting the .sh file. Its not, no log is produced. So it seems that its not even attempting to start the .sh file.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

`/usr/bin/php -f /root/scripts/twitter/update.php`

I added the full path of the php file in the .sh
I am wondering if `crontab` is running the sh files from another location, meaning it could not find a local file `update.php`. By specifying the path, I am saying run THIS version, not the one that could be in the dir you are run from.